# Transaction Response Time For Particular Request in LoadRunner

Tags: loadrunner

In my script I have 10 transactions, but I want to capture only 3,5,7 transaction response times in one transaction.

Need your valuable answers for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capture all ten timing events.  Filter out the seven you do not want when you get to analysis and then report on the three you are interested in.